# How can I properly create / initiate a GTLRSheets_ValueRange update of Google Sheets?

Tags: objective-c, google-sheets-api, google-api-objc-client

I'm trying to update a cell in a Google Sheets spreadsheet..... `superRange` in this case is `A328:A` and I'm getting the message

```
2018-05-10 11:53:16.434032-0700 LAADyeApp[3252:1832239] Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "a328:_a" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.

NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @{ superRange: @"test" } , nil];
GTLRSheets_ValueRange *value;
NSMutableDictionary *datum = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: @{ @"values": data }];
value = [GTLRSheets_ValueRange objectWithJSON:datum];
GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate *query2 = [GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate queryWithObject:value spreadsheetId:spreadsheetId range:superRange];


[self.service executeQuery:query2
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];
```

heres some debug data

```
2018-05-10 11:53:15.318726-0700 LAADyeApp[3252:1832239] Testing range: A328:A
2018-05-10 11:53:15.318863-0700 LAADyeApp[3252:1832239] Getting sheet data...
2018-05-10 11:53:15.335954-0700 LAADyeApp[3252:1832239] OK: (
        {
        "A328:A" = test;
    }
)
2018-05-10 11:53:16.434032-0700 LAADyeApp[3252:1832239] Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "a328:_a" at 'data.values[0]': Cannot find field.
```

How can I properly create / initialize a `GTLRSheets_ValueRange`, and then update it?

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: [self.service executeQuery:query2
                  delegate:self
         didFinishSelector:@selector(displayResultWithTicket:finishedWithObject:error:)];

Comment: The error says your data is not valid JSON.

Comment: Can you show me how to properly format this?

Comment: You haven't shown your JSON data.

Comment: I just need to update the  A328:A field with the string "RECEIVED"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170814/discussion-between-digit-and-koen).